# PHP IIS 500.0 on specific remote mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I am trying to hunt down a bug: I have a php script, which queries the DB. I have two boxes, machine A (PHP 5.6) and machine B (PHP 7.3.1). IIS runs on both and MySQL 5.6 runs on machine A. php runs on both as a FastCGI process.

When the script runs on machine A (where mysql server is), it always runs perfectly well.
When the script runs on machine B about 30% of the time IIS returns an error `500.0`

There are 4-5 queries in the script, but I have narrowed the crash down to the following query, this is the only one causing the trouble some times (non deterministically):

```
require_once('pdoconnection.php');
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");

$sTableName = "mytable";
$devicealready = 6;
$CodeID = "3242342";

$authuser_PRST = $MYPDO->prepare("UPDATE " . $sTableName . " SET CurrentMaxDevice = :CurrentMaxDevice WHERE Code = :Code");
$authuser_PRST->bindValue(":CurrentMaxDevice", $devicealready);
$authuser_PRST->bindValue(":Code", $CodeID);

echo "here@".$devicealready."#".$CodeID."#".$sTableName."#";
$authuser_PRST->execute() or die($MYPDO->errorInfo());
```

pdoconnection.php:

```
$hostname_ABC = "1.1.1.1";
$database_ABC = "mydb";
$username_ABC = "myuser";
$password_ABC = "mypass";

$errorreporting = error_reporting();

try {
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
    $MYPDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".$hostname_ABC.";dbname=".$database_ABC, $username_ABC, $password_ABC, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING, PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 2));
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $MYPDO = null;
}

error_reporting($errorreporting);
```

How can I figure out what is going on? logs (mysql and php) don't show anything and IIS logs only show error 500.0

Comment: Check the php [error log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log). That is where you should be looking for errors.

Comment: @SalmanA no such thing as an indication of error in error_log

Comment: ok I just found the issue: if I turn `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` to false, everything runs smoothly, no 500.0 error. I don't know why

Comment: What exactly does `error_log` setting in php.ini say? If it is not set, use a value such as `error_log = C:/windows/temp/php-errors.log` and test the page a couple of times until it fails.

Comment: @SalmanA the error file (I know which one is it) displayed no errors whatsoever. If I turn off persistent connections, the problem goes away and I don't know why

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.